# Course of Study and Career Options

Tags: careers

I am facing a bit of a quandary and would greatly appreciate the advice of some experts. Thank you in advance!

I graduated as a Math and Physics double major a few years ago. I have worked in data analysis and software development roles and now find myself in, effectively, AI research. I am unhappy in this position and believe work as a statistician would suit me better. I can provide additional background details if they would be helpful.

I am on track to start classes through the distance learning program at Texas A&M leading to an M.S. in Statistics this Spring. I have read great things about the content of the program and would be proud to become an Aggie, but I have seen less about its utility in enabling a career transition like in my case. I am also concerned about working a demanding full-time position and balancing my studies. I want to derive the full benefit from the degree, but I have also devoted the majority of my free time since college to furthering my career. Bluntly, I am highly dissatisfied with my life (more accurately, lack thereof) outside of the office and worry about my ability to endure a few years filled with a job I dislike and continued alienation from others that rigorous study requires. My employer offers some tuition reimbursement, but I would be obligated to remain with the company for a period after completing my degree or else need to repay the full reimbursement amount.

Alternatively, I have high confidence I could complete an M.S. at a university of similar stature to Texas A&M with a stipend and tuition waiver. The stipend is a significant decrease from my current salary but sufficient to cover my annual expenses, and my time has become an increasingly important commodity. This approach also appeals to me because, although I understand graduate school is not the same as the first few years of undergrad, I see an increased ability to build a network and take advantage of recruitment, meet and become close to like-minded individuals, and provide myself with sufficient time to master the material. That being said, leaving a well-paying position in times like these seems ill-advised and my current work is probably relevant enough to count as experience towards my new career. I also acknowledge that I might be running away from something I perceive as "hard" to an environment (the university) where I was successful and comfortable in the past.

Has anyone else encountered a similar situation? What factors should I use to make this decision? Which route is more likely to lead to professional and personal success, and does the answer to that question depend on specific industries? I know I must, ultimately, make the choice, but I have spent too much time in my own head and neglected to talk to experienced statisticians up to this point. Thank you again for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Hi: I can't answer your question but the question that arises in my mind is: "is your masters in statistics going to lead to a better position that AI research ?". Ask yourself what is wrong with your current position and if a masters or higher degree in stat will  be likely to change that ? I'm not so sure because AI research doesn't sound like a bad job to me. Just my two cents of course. And a job can definitely have its negative components ( colleagues for example could be difficult ) regardless of its content.

Comment: Graduate school is tough; working full-time at the same time is all you'll be able to manage. If you want to work and do graduate school at the same time, don't expect to do ANYTHING else. 

A lot of statisticians end up doing AI work, anyway. What kind of work do you really want to do? Or is the problem more your supervisor? In my experience, a bad supervisor makes even the best work horrid, while a great supervisor can make even less-than-ideal work just fine. Keyword: look for "servant leadership" in your supervisor.

Comment: @mlofton Thank you for your insights! AI research is one of the most exciting fields in which one can work, and I am fortunate in that respect. I have somehow managed to obtain a role one typically needs a PhD for and am, in my estimation, unqualified to make an approximately lateral move due to my lack of formal education or into a more applied role due to the research orientation of my work activities thus far. I desire to both change organizations and work in an applied role. I want to make a tangible difference now, and my current research activities do not lend themselves to that goal.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I suspected the demands you described were true. My goal is to address problems using mathematical and statistical methods, which, as you said, might lead me back to AI if that approach serves the situation. My supervisor and current place of work are almost certainly coloring my view of things - I desire to be a servant leader myself and do not see any examples to which I can aspire. As I mentioned in my answer to mlofton, I feel 'stuck' in my current situation and am unsure of an approach that would serve me better than the degree. I am open to alternatives, though. Thank you.

Comment: Albert: I would ask yourself if you're interested in more education or just more of an applied job. If the former, then you should think about a Ph.D which is obviously more of a longer term comittment. As the other person said, only you can really make the right decision. I always think that, whatever decision you make, as long as you put enough thought into it, is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to become clear on the very specific things that you do not like about your current job. Are you not challenge? Lacks creativity? The hours? Colleagues? Benefits? Helping a corporation earn more profits? From there, you can think about what specifically you want in a new job, and whether the degree in Stats will help you get there. This can also help you determine how much risk you are willing to take, e.g. leave your current job or not. If you know your future job will be far superior, and there are many openings, then you can take the risk of saying bye. Maybe you have already considered these things, but knowing where you want to go and why is helpful. I would agree that working fulltime and going to school fulltime will be tough. My graduate program was more than a fulltime job. I'd also say that you are examining some very complex, deep questions, and no person's situation is going to be the same. If your job offers health insurance, and it includes mental health coverage, I would recommend reaching out a therapist. What you are discussing is a life transition, and there are professionals who are better equipped to walk you through what will be best for YOU! It's your life, not ours, and you can only do what feels right for you.

Comment: Thank you. I started seeing a therapist to help me identify which aspects are driving me to seek a change. I believe my question for this community is more along the lines of understanding the likely results of either the part-time or full-time educational path. I can address the life transition itself with the therapist, but I do not believe he or I have adequate knowledge about the career field. E.g., is the TAMU degree, in practice, only useful for people trying to move ahead in their current job and, thus, a return to school is necessary for career or industry-area changers?

Comment: I'll add that there are certain jobs that require at least an MA, and without that advanced degree, you won't get past HR for an interview. Additionally, an advanced degree comes with more critical thinking skills on methods, techniques, in a very nuanced way. Particular employers appreciate this. I would not be able to have my job without an advanced degree. Everyone has at least an MA. So if you're future job requires that, I would get the degree. If you can balance both a fulltime job and your studies, great, but school must come fist. You'll need your professors' recommendation letters.